# class instance selection of a function return value

Tags: haskell

I want to print the return type of a function ("Integer" in this case):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Default

class HasReturnType a where
  getReturnType :: a -> String

instance Default a => HasReturnType (a->b) where
  getReturnType f = getReturnType (f def)

instance HasReturnType Integer where
  getReturnType _ = "Integer"

instance {-# Overlappable #-} HasReturnType a where
  getReturnType _ = "<unmatched case>"

inc :: Integer -> Integer
inc = (+1)

main = do
  putStrLn $ getReturnType inc
```

Instead, it is printing "<unmatched case>".  It seems odd to me, since the return type of `inc::Integer->Integer` is clearly an `Integer`.

Is it possible to match on the instance of the return value type of a function call like this?

(The example is silly, it is a toy snippet based on something more complicated.  I'm just trying to understand why it isn't matching the more concrete instance.)

Comment: Take away the `instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} HasReturnType a ...`. You should then get a rejection message that'll tell you what type GHC is trying to resolve. BTW notice the uppercase spelling.

Comment: Why are you even using `Data.Default`? You don't want to return a value, because `def` picks some arbitrary value, and applying `f` to it might fail at runtime or loop etc. (The suggested answer uses `Data.Typeable`; I don't see the need for that either.)

Comment: without that case I get an error ```Could not deduce (HasReturnType b) arising from a use of ‘getReturnType’ from the context: Default a```....  I guess another way to ask the question is, how do I get it to use the instance for Integer, since it is an Integer?

Comment: The type and Default stuff is just secondary stuff put in to simplify a larger problem for easy digestion here....  You can ignore it, my main question is "why isn't it using the ```instance HasReturnType Integer``` when it is actually that type.  The actual original use case was about deferred evaluation of functions in a language loaded and executed at runtime, where I pass around full expressions that need to be fed to functions and evaluated repeatedly with different variables.  The toy ```getReturnType``` thing was just a simplification to illustrate something broken in the full example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```hs
    {-# LANGUAGE  FlexibleInstances, ScopedTypeVariables  #-}

    module FuncReturn  where
    
        class HasReturnType a  where
            getReturnType :: a -> String
        instance HasReturnType b => HasReturnType (a -> b)  where
            getReturnType f = getReturnType $ f undefined
    --  instance HasReturnType b => HasReturnType (a -> b)  where
    --      getReturnType f = getReturnType (undefined :: b)
                          -- needs ScopedTypeVariables ^^^^    

        instance HasReturnType Integer  where
            getReturnType _ = "Integer"
        instance HasReturnType Int  where
            getReturnType _ = "Int"
        instance HasReturnType String  where
            getReturnType _ = "String"
        instance HasReturnType Bool  where
            getReturnType _ = "Bool"
        
        instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} HasReturnType ab  where
            getReturnType _ = "<unmatched case>"
```

--  getReturnType length ===> "Int"

--  getReturnType (&&)   ===> "Bool"

--  getReturnType (+)    ===> ERROR - Unresolved overloading  Type: (Num a, hasReturnType a) => [Char]

```hs
    inc :: Integer -> Integer
    inc = undefined               -- doesn't need a binding
```

-- getReturnType inc  ===> "Integer"

Comment: great answer, and you are right, the Default part wasn't needed.  My code is working now.

Answer (score 3):

Compare your instance:

```
instance (Default a) => HasReturnType (a->b) where
  getReturnType f = getReturnType (f def)
```

with this variant (difference underlined):

```
instance (Default a, HasReturnType b) => HasReturnType (a->b) where
                     ---------------
  getReturnType f = getReturnType (f def)
```

In the former instance, the call `getReturnType (f def)` requires to solve the constraint `HasReturnType b`. GHC immediately tries to resolve that, when `b` is still unknown, and the only instance that applies is the generic "unmatched case" one, so it commits to that.

By contrast, the the latter instance we can resolve the constraint using the larger context: this makes GHC choose that, effectively delaying the choice of the instance from this call point to the one in `main`. Hence that works.

Thumb rule: GHC tries to solve constraints at each call point. If you don't want to commit to a specific instance at that point, you need to provide the constraint in the context, so that selection is delayed. (Of course, if we don't use overlapping instances the exact point where GHC commits to an instance is immaterial.)

Answer (score 0):

your example is incorrect.
The only valid codepath is going through the default case. It's short circuiting the typeclass instance resolution.

A fixed example that fill do what you expect is:

```
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Typeable

class Default a where
  def :: a

instance Default Integer where
  def = 1

class HasReturnType a where
  getReturnType :: a -> String

instance (Default a, Typeable b) => HasReturnType (a->b) where
  getReturnType f = show . typeOf $ f def

instance  {-# Overlappable #-} HasReturnType a where
  getReturnType _ = "<unmatched case>"

instance HasReturnType Integer where
  getReturnType _ = "Integer"

inc :: Integer -> Integer
inc = (+1)

main = do
  putStrLn $ getReturnType inc
```

Comment: thanks for the attempt, but this shows the type by using Data.Typeable....  The question was about how to get the program to call the HasReturnType instance for Integer, and this doesn't do that.  (remember, the use case was a toy, I just want to know how to get it to call the instance of the returned type).  Here I could even remove the instance I'm trying to call, and it would still work by calling typeOf.

Comment: put another way....  the question is, "why is there only a path through the default instance?".  I would have guessed that the Integer version of HasReturnType would have been called, because the type is in fact an Integer.

Comment: A possible benefit from `Typeable` is your datatypes can just say `deriving Typeable`, without needing to declare a `instance HasReturnType`. I suspect the code here won't return what o.p. expects for a dyadic operator.